# Finding backup winZ for glm::unProject

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

I have an OpenGL program that basically just renders a bunch of points. I need to find the world-space coordinates from an arbitrary cursor position, which I do like this:

```
glm::mat4 modelview = graphics.view*graphics.model;
glm::vec4 viewport = { 0.0, 0.0, windowWidth, windowHeight };

float winX = cursorX;
float winY = viewport[3] - cursorY;
float winZ;

glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);
glm::vec3 screenCoords = { winX, winY, winZ };

glm::vec3 cursorPosition = glm::unProject(screenCoords, modelview, graphics.projection, viewport);
```

This works fine if the cursor is on an object, but if it's on an empty part of the screen (i.e. most of it), it's assumed to be on the far clipping plane (winZ = 1), and glm::unProject returns inf values. Ideally, I'd like to pass it a different winZ corresponding to the xy plane at z=0 in world space coordinates, but I can't figure out how to get that value.

Comment: `z_win=1` being un-projected to infinity would imply that you're using an infinite far plane. Then, you should never feed `z_win=1` into the unproject function. "I'd like to pass it a different winZ corresponding to the xy plane at z=0 " in which space? I'd assume that xy-plane is still supposed to be parallel to the near plane?

Comment: That's a good point, I should have mentioned that I'm using an infinitePerspective projection. "xy plane at z=0" is in world space coordinates, and it is parallel to the near plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is a [`glm::unProject`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00666.html#ga36641e5d60f994e01c3d8f56b10263d2) function, the is a [`glm::project`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00666.html#gaf36e96033f456659e6705472a06b6e11) function too.

If you want to know the depth of a point, which is located on parallel plane to the view space, with a z-coordinate of 0, then you have to `glm::project` a point on this plane. It can be any point on the plane, because you are only interested in its z-coordinate. You can use the origin of the world for this:

```
glm::vec3 world_origin{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
glm::vec3 origin_ndc = glm::project(screenCoords, view, graphics.projection, viewport);
float depth0         = world_origin[2];
```

where `view` is the view matrix, which transforms from world space to camera space (got from [`glm::lookAt`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00668.html#gaa64aa951a0e99136bba9008d2b59c78e)).

So the implementation may look like this:

```
glm::mat4 modelview = graphics.view * graphics.model;
glm::vec4 viewport  = { 0.0, 0.0, windowWidth, windowHeight };

float winX = cursorX;
float winY = viewport[3] - cursorY;
float depth;
glReadPixels(winX, winY- cursorY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth);

const float epsi = 0.00001f;
if ( depth > 1.0f-epsi )
{
    glm::vec3 world_origin{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    glm::vec3 origin_ndc = glm::project(world_origin, graphics.view, graphics.projection, viewport);
    depth                = origin_ndc[2];  
}

glm::vec3 screenCoords{ winX, winY, depth };
glm::vec3 cursorPosition = glm::unProject(screenCoords, modelview, graphics.projection, viewport);
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to work quite well. I'm just going to wait a bit before accepting so that others have a chance to submit an answer. I'm wondering though, is the value of epsi arbitrary, or is there some background to that?  I ask  because even when glReadPixels gives a valid depth, it is still very close to 1. for example, 0.999950409. Not sure if I should be concerned about it ending up in that if() incorrectly

Comment: @Imoyn In this case the epsilon may not be needed, because the depth is read by `glReadPixels` and should be exactly 1.0 (if the value of [`glClearDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearDepth.xhtml)). But may be it depends on the format of the depth buffer and the graphics driver. Who knows? So possibly you can completely skip it and for sure you can decrease it.